# It is allowed to have empty tags or branches directories in SVN when tags or branches are not used?

Tags: svn

I was searching but cannot find the answer of the question:

Is it allowed to have empty tags or branches directories in SVN when tags or branches are not used? Is there a documentation that clarifies that?

Thanks,
Martin

Comment: AFAIK there's no mandatory directory structure in SVN, so you can do whatever you want with branches and tags.

Answer (score 5):

You can create whatever nodes you want inside subversion. That is up to you.

Subversion is in fact a hierarchical file system with an additional time dimension.